How to calculate the Maintainability Index of my code?
I'm creating unit test for my code in R and one of the metrics I need to calculate is the Mantainability Index. I'm using testthat for creating my tests, but they do not provide this metric. I have taken the definition of Python's radon package as reference. However, I haven't been able to find an R package that calculates this index. Has anyone encountered this problem before? How can I calculate this metric?
I tried searching for a package in CRAN/Bioconductor, even with chatGPT (But it suggests using lintr, which is not what I'm looking for).

I edited your question so it complies to the rules better, since "is there a package" questions are forbidden (not my rules!). lintr does have some tools to detect code with cyclomatic complexity above a threshold, but indeed AFAIK not the index you're looking for

I'm happy to put a bounty on this if you don't get a satisfying answer (ping me later if so), I'd like that as well. the cyclocomp might help too. global cyclomatic complexity is not defined on your linked page AFAICT however, do you know how to compute it ?
